# Filter red pixels in an image with PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging

currently I am trying to detect red pixels inside a small picture (about 360*360 pixels).

The images have a broad range of red-values which is why I can't just iterate over all pixels and check for a certain rgb-value.

What would some efficient ways be to analyze such a picture to get the percentage of pixels which are perceived as red by humans?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends on the human. You have to decide the threshold yourself.

Comment: How could I describe such a color range in RGB though?

Comment: Is it necessary that it be *perceived* as "this colour is red"? Could you just use the sum of the total R in the RGB? So orange and purple contribute to the total, but green and blue don't.

Comment: Yes. That is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the image into HSV color space. Then the croma will be determined just by the H value. So you could put a threshold only on H to get red color.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you!